# Will these code be safe in memory in c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a question about the following code.

First, these codes worked well.

However, there is no declaration only defined about “courses” in class Student.If in the Constructor of Student the argument is constant, will these code be safe?
Thanks for helping!:)

```
public class Student
{
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public string[] courses;
    public Student(string _name, int _age,params string[] _courses)
    {
        name = _name;
        age = _age;

        courses = _courses;//is this OK if _courses is constant?


    }
}
public class work : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Start()
    {
       /*
        string[] courses={"math", "English"};
        Student Tom = new Student("Tom",18,courses);
        //It's wrong!
       */
        Student Tom = new Student("Tom", 18, "math", "English");
        string Tom_text = JsonUtility.ToJson(Tom);
        Debug.Log(Tom_text);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should edit you question have no clue what is it you wanted to ask?  Do you want to ask if it's ok to pass an array as params argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you have it, anyone can change the `Student` object at anytime.

If you do not want anyone changing anything about the `Student` object once it has been created, then make it *immutable* like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Courses { get; private set; }
    public Student(string name, int age, params string[] courses)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;

        this.Courses = courses;
    }
}
```

Now people cannot change the the properties because the setters are private.

And to follow the .NET naming convention, do not use `-` underscores in parameter names and use *Pascal Notation* for property names. I have removed the underscores and used *Pascal Notation* for property names.

**EDIT**

@diemaus mentioned a good point in the comments to this answer, in C# 6:

> You can actually remove the private set entirely, and just leave it `{ get; }`. This is allowed as long as long as you only set the properties in the constructor.

Comment: You can actually remove the `private set` entirely, and just leave it `{ get; }`. This is allowed as long as long as you only set the properties in the constructor.

Comment: @diemaus wow I have to admit, after years of development with C#, I had no idea that is allowed. Thanks for this tip: Very useful.

Comment: Only in c# 6. And not to nitpick but your code is not really immutable. When you leave out the get it will create a readonly field where with the set the field is not readonly and you can still change it. . also in 6 you can do `public string Name { get; set; } = "asd";` not really related but really cool

Comment: @FilipCordas diemaus did not say to remove `get` but to remove `set`. And no it cannot be mutated from outside.

Comment: As @FilipCordas points out. It's a C# 6-feature, and will not work in versions below. [Version 6 actually included a lot of useful language-features](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-framework/whats-new-in-c-6/), check them out! Should I also point out that the `this`-keyword is redundant as well? Or is that simply your programming style?

Comment: @diemaus Yes `this` is a preference and I never write code without it. Will check it out.

Comment: Thank you for helping! To be honesty ,I didn't expect my code to have so many small problems, your comments really help me a lot! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @hzshang you are welcome. The question still remains unanswered until you accept it. Did you need any more clarity?